# Sorting apalike bibtex citations of same author, same year

Tags: bibtex, citing

This may look like a duplicate but believe me, it isn't (at least I could not find a similar issue). I've been trying to cite two papers from the same author in apalike style on Overleaf and it does not seem to work on the order it is supposed to.

I took the suggestion from the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/437869/twin-reference-in-wrong-order) to alter apalike to apalike-month and am using that on Overleaf. That solved the issue for a couple citations, but a pair of them is still giving me trouble. Here are they:

```
@article{silvestro_bayesian_2014,
    title = {Bayesian {Estimation} of {Speciation} and {Extinction} from {Incomplete} {Fossil} {Occurrence} {Data}},
    volume = {63},
    issn = {1063-5157},
    url = {https://doi.org/10.1093/sysbio/syu006},
    doi = {10.1093/sysbio/syu006},
    number = {3},
    urldate = {2021-02-03},
    journal = {Systematic Biology},
    author = {Silvestro, Daniele and Schnitzler, Jan and Liow, Lee Hsiang and Antonelli, Alexandre and Salamin, Nicolas},
    month = may,
    year = {2014},
    pages = {349--367},
}

@article{silvestro_pyrate_2014,
    title = {{PyRate}: {A} new program to estimate speciation and extinction rates from incomplete fossil data},
    volume = {5},
    shorttitle = {{PyRate}},
    doi = {10.1111/2041-210X.12263},
    journal = {Methods in Ecology and Evolution},
    author = {Silvestro, Daniele and Salamin, Nicolas and Schnitzler, Jan},
    month = sep,
    year = {2014},
}
```

These were generated from Zotero, so I'm hoping there's nothing super wrong with them. As you can see they have the same author, same year, and different months (such that the first one here should be first, as it came out in may). Still, the former appears as 2014b, and the latter as 2014a. I've tried changing the order of the list of citations, changing titles slightly, and nothing works. From the .bst file it would seem they are being sorted in the `sort.label` part of the code? I don't know enough about .bst to confirm it, however.

The minimal version of tex

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\cite{silvestro_bayesian_2014, silvestro_pyrate_2014}

\bibliographystyle{apalike-month.bst}
\bibliography{refs.bib}

\end{document}
```